# How do you include newlines in a python list unpack?

Tags: python, list, newline, iterable-unpacking

```
for row in rows:
    a, b, c = row
```

is nice but

```
for row in rows:
    alpha, beta, charlie, delta, echo, foxtrot, gamma, horseshoe, indigo, jimmy, killshot = row
```

is not very nice.  Python is usually good about supporting newlines after commas but I can't figure out the syntax for this one.  Something like this would be nice:

```
for row in rows:
    alpha, 
    beta, 
    charlie, 
    delta, 
    echo, 
    foxtrot, 
    gamma, 
    horseshoe, 
    indigo, 
    jimmy, 
    killshot = row
```

What is the PEP 8 way to handle this, since long lines are anti-PEP 8?

Comment: I would avoid unpacking in the first place if you have this many values. A list is a very natural way to store a sequence of data, so why deviate from it? If you need a clear way to reference different items, then just define a few constants and index your list as follows: `x = row[ALPHA]` (assuming you've defined `ALPHA = 0`)

Comment: The list is a set of results from a sql query.  I'm unpacking them to work with the values in code.  Isn't it cleaner to unpack them into appropriately named variables like above than to have to use the list with an index (even if the index is a constant)?

Comment: Eh, I guess that's more of a preference thing. Another option would be to use a `namedtuple`.

Comment: 'Named tuples are especially useful for assigning field names to result tuples returned by the csv or sqlite3 modules' - HA, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
for row in rows:
    (alpha, 
     beta, 
     charlie, 
     delta, 
     echo, 
     foxtrot, 
     gamma, 
     horseshoe, 
     indigo, 
     jimmy, 
     killshot) = row
```

Personally, I'd probably use more than one item per line (breaking where the lines get long, or where there's a logical change in the meaning of the items), but as long as you're consistent I think the style above would be fine too.

Comment: That's so easy it's embarrassing.  Thanks!